# Current state of development using Microsoft BotFramework

Tags: software-development, c#, azure

I was redirected to here from [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76839421/current-state-of-development-using-microsoft-botframework).

Currently we are in process of building a Slack bot using Microsoft BotFramework but there is so much confusion around development and what is actively supported that it is turning out to be a roadblock one after the other.

- Firstly, there is [Choose the right chatbot solution for your use case](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-overview?view=azure-bot-service-4.0)
- Then, [The future of bot building](https://powervirtualagents.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/the-future-of-bot-building/)

Looking at the above, and since we have dotnet developers, we decided to continue with [dotnet SDK](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet)

Now, there is a separate Slack adapter supported by the community [botbuilder-community-dotnet](https://github.com/BotBuilderCommunity/botbuilder-community-dotnet). We had to use this because we wanted some features that were not supported by Azure Slack channel *(e.g. BlockKit messages)*.
There are a lot of issues with this library which is not actively developed and lacks samples.

I have fixed a few and created PRs for them

- [Added function to convert SigninCard to BlockKit](https://github.com/BotBuilderCommunity/botbuilder-community-dotnet/pull/539)
- [Changed AzureAdAuthentication documentation to refer correct variable](https://github.com/BotBuilderCommunity/botbuilder-community-dotnet/pull/537)

I have raised an issue as well

- https://github.com/BotBuilderCommunity/botbuilder-community-dotnet/issues/540

So my question is what is the latest approach to develop using Microsoft BotFramework with Slack so that we can use BlockKit, reply as a thread, etc., and has active community support?

Comment: For context, original question on SO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76839421/current-state-of-development-using-microsoft-botframework